# How do the NEC Article 460 requirements apply to small capacitors mounted outside of equipment?

Tags: capacitor, mains

NEC Article 460 discusses the use of capacitors in electrical circuits outside of equipment.  However, these requirements are designed for large power capacitors, oftentimes using liquid dielectrics or cooling systems, and enclosed in metal cases that must be grounded, with their own protection and disconnecting means.  How would the Article 460 requirements apply to a *small* capacitor (say a 100nF X capacitor), with no liquids and a nonconductive case, deployed directly into an electrical circuit (say, for interference suppression)?

Answer (score 1):

Article 460 does not apply. However, the only way a small capacitor can be connected to a circuit covered by by the NEC is by incorporation into a device or piece of equipment that is approved and installed according to the requirements of the NEC.

Comment: Can you explain why Article 460 fails to apply? Nothing in the scope of the article says anything about it applying only to some varieties of capacitors found outside of equipment (well, there is the text about surge capacitors, but I suspect that doesn't apply to our discussion)

Comment: Yes. The text about the surge capacitors etc. means that other capacitors are excluded.